# How to bind keys to a function which can be defined per-mode?

Tags: functions, local-variables

Currently I have variables defined with `setq-local`, this is useful for modes, so I can define variables only for a particular mode.

How can this be done for functions?

I'd like to have a function, eg:
`generic-lookup-reference-at-point`, bind this to a key, then define it for each mode which has the ability to lookup an item under the cursor.

Comment: It's the same as for anything. Just assign the function to the variable.

Answer (score 8):

```lisp
(defvar my-local-variable nil
"Variable used on a bufer-local basis to indicate ...")

(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-local-variable)
```

USAGE:

```lisp
(setq my-local-variable (lambda () (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode)))

(define-key name-of-major-mode-keymap [f5]
  (lambda () (interactive)
             (funcall my-local-variable)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `defvar` instead of `defvar-local`?

Comment: It is possible that `defvar-local` came into being after my introduction to Emacs ... If it has the same effect as `defvar` followed by `make-variable-buffer-local`, then by all means consolidate the two into one ... :)  I still have several libraries that use the `defvar` / `make-variable-buffer-local` combination and I've never tried `defvar-local`.

Comment: That is indeed precisely what it does.  Introduced (along with `setq-local`) in 24.3, so both macros are pretty safe to make use of in general at this point.

Comment: Just `nil` as default looks wrong. The old way is to replace `(funcall my-local-variable)` by something like `(funcall (or my-local-variable #'my-default-function))`. The new way is to use `#'my-default-function` as default value for `my-local-variable`.

Comment: Agree `nil` as default isn't great, wrote a macro that sets a placeholder function, here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51244/2418

Answer (score 2):

If a library developer is responsible for definining the mode dependent behavior and
you do not plan to allow the user to change it per `defcustom` you can use mode dependent overloads.

The code below is for playing around with mode local overrides. In buffers derived from `text-mode` <kbd>[f9]</kbd> prints "action in  text-mode." in other buffers it prints "default action."

```el
(require 'mode-local)

(define-overload lookup-reference-at-point (point) ;
  "Default lookup for reference at POINT."
  (interactive "d")
  (:override
   (message "This is the")
   (message "default action.")))

(define-mode-local-override lookup-reference-at-point text-mode (point)
  "Lookup for reference at POINT in `text-mode'."
  (message "This is the")
  (message "action in text-mode."))

(global-set-key [f9] #'lookup-reference-at-point)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Posting answer to own question, including an example.*

As @lawlist points out this can be done using `defvar-local`, this example uses macros to avoid writing boiler plate code and prints a message if the function isn't defined, runs a fallback function.

```lisp
(defmacro my-generic-fn-with-fallback (var description &rest body)
  `
  (progn
    (defun ,var ()
      ,description
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively ,var))
    (defvar-local ,var ,@body "Value storing a function, called by a function of the same name.")))

(defmacro my-generic-fn (var description)
  `
  (my-generic-fn-with-fallback ,var ,description
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (message "Mode <%s> doesn't define <%s>, doing nothing!" major-mode ',var))))

(my-generic-fn my-generic-run "Run the current buffer")
(my-generic-fn my-generic-goto-thing-at-point "Go to symbol at the point")
(my-generic-fn my-generic-usage-of-thing-at-point "References to symbol point")

(my-generic-fn-with-fallback my-generic-jump-next "Jump forward"
                             'evil-jump-forward)
(my-generic-fn-with-fallback my-generic-jump-prev "Jump backward"
                             'evil-jump-backward)

(my-generic-fn-with-fallback my-generic-doc-jump-section "Jump to sections"
                             'imenu)
```

Then each mode can set functions:

```lisp
(add-hook
 'diff-mode-hook
 (lambda ()

   ;; --- snip

   ;; Generic functions
   ;; 'my-generic-run (no need)
   (setq my-generic-goto-thing-at-point 'diff-goto-source-and-close)
   (setq my-generic-jump-next 'diff-goto-source-and-close)
   (setq my-generic-jump-prev 'kill-buffer-and-window)
   ;; Lambda's work too.
   (setq my-generic-doc-jump-section (lambda () (interactive) (doc-jump-section-diff)))

   ;; --- snip

   )
 )
```

Bind the keys:

```lisp
;; global key example.
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (funcall my-generic-run)))

;; using evil-mode.
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-l") 'my-generic-jump-next)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-h") 'my-generic-jump-prev)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-RET") 'my-generic-goto-thing-at-point)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-S-u") 'my-generic-usage-of-thing-at-point)
```